# Primefaces Datatable some columns not rendered

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, rendering

I'm using Primefaces 5.1.5 with jsf 2.2. We used a dataTable in a tabView and populated it with data, some columns are not rendered?! I have inspected the page via developerTools and they really are not rendered as you can see here:
[image]

here is how we used the dataTable:

```
<p:dataTable emptyMessage="#{msgs['general.noEntriesFound']}"
                                            value="#{manageContracts.pricesForContract}" var="price"
                                            id="existingPrices" scrollHeight="200"
                                            sortBy="#{finalPrice.price}" scrollable="true"
                                            selectionMode="single" liveScroll="true" scrollRows="30"
                                            selection="#{manageContracts.selectedPrice}"
                                            rowKey="#{price.id}">
                                            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                                                listener="#{manageContracts.onPriceSelected}"
                                                update=":form:tabView:newPrice"></p:ajax>
                                            <f:facet name="header">
                                                <p:outputLabel value="#{msgs['contract.prices']}" />
                                            </f:facet>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['contract.distanceFrom']}"
                                                rendered="#{manageContracts.priceModelType == 'DISTANCE_BASED' || manageContracts.priceModelType == 'DISTANCE_BASED_NLC' || manageContracts.priceModelType == 'DISTANCE_BASED_NLC'}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.fromDistance}"
                                                filterBy="#{price.fromDistance}" filterMatchMode="contains"
                                                filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.fromDistance}">
                                                    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="0" />
                                                </h:outputText>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['contract.distanceFrom']}"
                                                rendered="#{manageContracts.priceModelType == 'DISTANCE_BASED' || manageContracts.priceModelType == 'DISTANCE_BASED_NLC'}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.toDistance}" filterBy="#{price.toDistance}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.toDistance}">
                                                    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="0" />
                                                </h:outputText>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['contract.from']}"
                                                rendered="#{manageContracts.priceModelType == 'REGION_BASED'}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.fromDescription}"
                                                filterBy="#{price.fromDescription}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.fromDescription}" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['contract.to']}"
                                                rendered="#{manageContracts.priceModelType == 'REGION_BASED'}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.toDescription}"
                                                filterBy="#{price.toDescription}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.toDescription}" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['general.brand']}"
                                                rendered="#{manageContracts.priceModelType != 'DISTANCE_BASED_NLC' and manageContracts.priceModelType != 'REGION_BASED_NLC'}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.brandName}" filterBy="#{price.brandName}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.brandName}" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['general.type']}"
                                                rendered="#{manageContracts.priceModelType != 'DISTANCE_BASED_NLC' and manageContracts.priceModelType != 'REGION_BASED_NLC'}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.typeName}" filterBy="#{price.typeName}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.typeName}" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['general.model']}"
                                                rendered="#{manageContracts.priceModelType != 'DISTANCE_BASED_NLC' and manageContracts.priceModelType != 'REGION_BASED_NLC'}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.modelName}" filterBy="#{price.modelName}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.modelName}" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['contract.sizeCategory']}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.wrapped.sizeCategory.categoryName}"
                                                filterBy="#{price.wrapped.sizeCategory.categoryName}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%"
                                                rendered="#{manageContracts.priceModelType == 'DISTANCE_BASED_NLC' || manageContracts.priceModelType == 'REGION_BASED_NLC'}">
                                                <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{price.wrapped.sizeCategory.categoryName}" />
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column
                                                headerText="#{msgs['contract.price']} (#{manageContracts.currency.name()})"
                                                sortBy="#{price.finalPrice.price}"
                                                filterBy="#{price.finalPrice.price}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.finalPrice.price}">
                                                    <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2"
                                                        minFractionDigits="2" />
                                                </h:outputText>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['contract.validFrom']}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.priceValidityFrom}"
                                                filterBy="#{price.priceValidityFrom}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.priceValidityFrom}">
                                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
                                                        timeZone="#{dateUtils.timeZone}" />
                                                </h:outputText>
                                            </p:column>
                                            <p:column headerText="#{msgs['contract.validTo']}"
                                                sortBy="#{price.priceValidityTo}"
                                                filterBy="#{price.priceValidityTo}"
                                                filterMatchMode="contains" filterStyle="width: 100%">
                                                <h:outputText value="#{price.priceValidityTo}">
                                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
                                                        timeZone="#{dateUtils.timeZone}" />
                                                </h:outputText>
                                            </p:column>
                                        </p:dataTable>
```

anyone got an Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You have combined a few conditions in `rendered` attribute of `<p:column>`, please check if they are working as expected.

I recommend you to copy the value of `rendered` attribute and paste anywhere else, so you can inspect in your page... Just to check if they are all `true`, if it's not, then the column won't render.

```
      ....
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
#{manageContracts.priceModelType == 'DISTANCE_BASED' || manageContracts.priceModelType == 'DISTANCE_BASED_NLC'}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this didn't solve the issue. All values are set as expected, I did look it up in the dev tools as you supposed to do. The strange thing is that the columns like Price is not shown, but there is no rendered attribute defined in the column definition...